# How do I setup AWS WorkMail for full domain redirection?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just setup a few accounts for our main domain (`example.com`) on AWS WorkMail. I now need all email sent to a secondary domain (`example.org`) so that every existing account and alias registered on the main domain receives al the email sent to the secondary domain.

Example: email sent to admin@example.org should be appear on admin@example.com

I thought of adding `example.org` to WorkMail domains and then configure an alias on every single address. But, is there a way to do it automatically, so that I don't have to add the alias on each new account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon WorkMail does not support wildcard email addresses. You will need to setup primary email addresses and any aliases for those email addresses.

Some name services support setting up email forwarding and support wildcards. Example Namecheap.

[How to set up a catch-all (wildcard) email address](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/310/2214/how-to-set-up-a-catchall-wildcard-email-address)

Be careful with a catch-all email address. Some spammers use dictionary attacks to send email to every possible name combination. You could wind up with a huge amount of email taking a lot of space that you are paying for.